# Remove expand/collapse all button from kartik expandrowcolumn header yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2, kartik-v

I want to remove the button to expand/collapse all on the `ExpandRowColumn` in gridview which i used kartik's widget. `'allowBatchToggle' => false` would only disable the button but not hide it entirely. I want to make it not visible.

**Column in gridview**

```
    [
        'class' => 'kartik\grid\ExpandRowColumn',
        'width' => '50px',
        'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
            return GridView::ROW_COLLAPSED;
        },
        'detailUrl' => Url::to(['/sysadmin/user/row-expand']),
        'expandOneOnly' => true,
        'allowBatchToggle' => false,
        'expandOneOnly' => true
    ],
```

Here it shows the icon i want to remove only in the headers.

[image]

Comment: Did you try `'allowBatchToggle' => false`?

Comment: Yes this works as intended and im using it now but the icon is still visible. Only way i can think of is tracing back to the css and making the color same as background haha. Thanks @MichalHynčica